# Why is my parallel code even slower than without parallelism?

Tags: haskell

I followed Simon Marlow's book on parallel Haskell (Chapter 1) using `rpar`/`rseq` .

Below is the code (Solving the Squid Game bridge simulation):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.DeepSeq (force)
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Data.Array.IO
  ( IOUArray,
    getAssocs,
    newListArray,
    readArray,
    writeArray,
  )
import Data.Functor ((<&>))
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Random (randomRIO)

game ::
  Int -> -- number of steps
  Int -> -- number of glass at each step
  Int -> -- number of players
  IO Int -- return the number of survivors
game totalStep totalGlass = go 1 totalGlass
  where
    go currentStep currentGlass numSurvivors
      | numSurvivors == 0 || currentStep > totalStep = return numSurvivors
      | otherwise = do
        r <- randomRIO (1, currentGlass)
        if r == 1
          then go (currentStep + 1) totalGlass numSurvivors
          else go currentStep (currentGlass - 1) (numSurvivors - 1)

simulate :: Int -> IO Int -> IO [(Int, Int)]
simulate n game =
  (newListArray (0, 16) (replicate 17 0) :: IO (IOUArray Int Int))
    >>= go 1
    >>= getAssocs
  where
    go i marr
      | i <= n = do
        r <- game
        readArray marr r >>= writeArray marr r . (+ 1)
        go (i + 1) marr
      | otherwise = return marr

main1 :: IO ()
main1 = do
  [n, steps, glassNum, playNum] <- getArgs <&> Prelude.map read
  res <- simulate n (game steps glassNum playNum)
  mapM_ print res

main2 :: IO ()
main2 = do
  putStrLn "Running main2"
  [n, steps, glassNum, playNum] <- getArgs <&> Prelude.map read
  res <- runEval $ do
    r1 <- rpar $ simulate (div n 2) (game steps glassNum playNum) >>= evaluate . force
    r2 <- rpar $ simulate (div n 2) (game steps glassNum playNum) >>= evaluate . force
    rseq r1
    rseq r2
    return $
      (\l1 l2 -> zipWith (\e1 e2 -> (fst e1, snd e1 + snd e2)) l1 l2)
        <$> r1
        <*> r2

  mapM_ print res

main = main2
```

For main2, I've compiled using:

```
ghc -O2 -threaded ./squid.hs
```

and run as:

```
./squid 10000000 18 2 16 +RTS -N2
```

I can't understand why `main1` is faster than `main2` while `main2` has parallelism in it.

Could anyone give me some comments on my code as to whether this is the correct use of parallelism?

**Update:**
Here's the updated version (the new `random` is quite cumbersome to use):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies (rpar, rseq, runEval)
import Data.Array.ST
  ( STUArray,
    getAssocs,
    newListArray,
    readArray,
    writeArray,
  )
import Data.Functor ((<&>))
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Random (StdGen)
import System.Random.Stateful
  ( StdGen,
    applySTGen,
    mkStdGen,
    runSTGen,
    uniformR,
  )

game ::
  Int -> -- number of steps
  Int -> -- number of glass at each step
  Int -> -- number of players
  StdGen ->
  ST s (Int, StdGen) -- return the number of survivors
game ns ng = go 1 ng
  where
    go
      !cs -- current step number
      !cg -- current glass number
      !ns -- number of survivors
      !pg -- pure generator
        | ns == 0 || cs > ns = return (ns, pg)
        | otherwise = do
          let (r, g') = runSTGen pg (applySTGen (uniformR (1, cg)))
          if r == 1
            then go (cs + 1) ng ns g'
            else go cs (cg - 1) (ns - 1) g'

simulate :: Int -> (forall s. StdGen -> ST s (Int, StdGen)) -> [(Int, Int)]
simulate n game =
  runST $
    (newListArray (0, 16) (replicate 17 0) :: ST s1 (STUArray s1 Int Int))
      >>= go 1 (mkStdGen n)
      >>= getAssocs
  where
    go !i !g !marr
      | i <= n = do
        (r, g') <- game g
        readArray marr r >>= writeArray marr r . (+ 1)
        go (i + 1) g' marr
      | otherwise = return marr

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [n, steps, glassNum, playNum] <- getArgs <&> Prelude.map read
  let res = runEval $ do
        r1 <- rpar $ simulate (div n 2 - 1) (game steps glassNum playNum)
        r2 <- rpar $ simulate (div n 2 + 1) (game steps glassNum playNum)
        rseq r1
        rseq r2
        return $ zipWith (\e1 e2 -> (fst e1, snd e1 + snd e2)) r1 r2
  mapM_ print res
```

**Update 2:**

Use pure code and the elapsed time is down to 7 seconds.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.ST ( runST, ST )
import Control.Parallel ( par, pseq )
import Data.Array.ST
    ( getAssocs, newListArray, readArray, writeArray, STUArray )
import Data.Functor ((<&>))
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Random (StdGen, uniformR, mkStdGen)
game ::
  Int -> -- number of total steps
  Int -> -- number of glass at each step
  Int -> -- number of players
  StdGen ->
  (Int, StdGen) -- return the number of survivors
game ts ng = go 1 ng
  where
    go
      !cs -- current step number
      !cg -- current glass number
      !ns -- number of survivors
      !pg -- pure generator
        | ns == 0 || cs > ts = (ns, pg)
        | otherwise = do
          let (r, g') = uniformR (1, cg) pg
          if r == 1
            then go (cs + 1) ng ns g'
            else go cs (cg - 1) (ns - 1) g'

simulate :: Int -> (StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)) -> [(Int, Int)]
simulate n game =
  runST $
    (newListArray (0, 16) (replicate 17 0) :: ST s1 (STUArray s1 Int Int))
      >>= go 1 (mkStdGen n)
      >>= getAssocs
  where
    go !i !g !marr
      | i <= n = do
        let (r, g') = game g
        readArray marr r >>= writeArray marr r . (+ 1)
        go (i + 1) g' marr
      | otherwise = return marr

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [n, steps, glassNum, playNum] <- getArgs <&> Prelude.map read

  let r1 = simulate (div n 2 - 1) (game steps glassNum playNum)
      r2 = simulate (div n 2 + 1) (game steps glassNum playNum)
      res = zipWith (\e1 e2 -> (fst e1, snd e1 + snd e2)) r1 r2

      res' = par r1 (pseq r2 res)

  mapM_ print res'
```

Comment: I don't see any good reason to use that `ST`-based generator. You can use `StateGenM StdGen` with `StateT StdGen (ST s)`, which should be faster. Or you can pass pure generators around manually, which seems a tad annoying.

Comment: @dfeuer thanks, much faster now.

Comment: @dfeuer i actually used the pure generator and switched the rpar/rseq pattern to par/pseq

Comment: `par` is sort of unofficially deprecated because it's hard for the runtime system to know when the result is still needed. I wouldn't use that.

Comment: @dfeuer, that's confusing because i saw par in the documentation of the latest ghc guide, and they use it as sort of the main example...

Comment: You expect documentation to be up to date or something??? Sheesh! It's not *officially* deprecated. There are also a few situations (not this one) where `par` might conceivably make more sense, but it's flakier, so it's better to avoid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't actually using any parallelism. You write

```hs
    r1 <- rpar $ simulate (div n 2) (game steps glassNum playNum) >>= evaluate . force
```

This sparks a thread to *evaluate* an `IO` action, not to *run* it. That's not useful.

Since your `simulate` is essentially *pure*, you should convert it from `IO` to `ST s` by swapping in the appropriate array types, etc. Then you can `rpar (runST $ simulate ...)` and actually do work in parallel. I don't *think* the `force` invocations are useful/appropriate in context; they'll free the arrays sooner, but at significant cost.

Comment: I did what you've suggested and indeed it's faster. But -N2 is still slower than -N1. Is this normal? Also, if I just run it like ./myprog without any +RTS, will the program run automatically in parallel?

Comment: @McBearHolden, there's often a lot of work involved in making parallel code actually win. In this case, I suspect you're not actually doing enough interesting work in each thread, compared to the amount you do to combine the results.